# Why cannot CCL load hunchentoot?

Tags: hunchentoot, ccl

SBCL can load hunchentoot successfully. However, the CCL reported:

```
? (ql:quickload :hunchentoot)
To load "hunchentoot":
Load 1 ASDF system:
hunchentoot
; Loading "hunchentoot"
> Error: Unable to load any of the alternatives:
>           ("libssl.so.0.9.8" "libssl.so" "libssl.so.4")
> While executing: CFFI::FL-ERROR, in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.nter code here
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need ssl (or will use Apache for this), you can

```
(push :hunchentoot-no-ssl *features*)
```

and then

```
(ql:quickload 'hunchentoot)
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. (push :HUNCHENTOOT-NO-SSL *features). colon, not single quote.

Comment: Great, one more potential hunchentoot-er :) don't forget to mark as answer.

Comment: Thanks :) If you need anything more with the instalation, don't hesitate to contact. I've currently installed hunchentoot on ubuntu, centos and windows (at work). I've encountered and solved some problems, so maybe I can help a little.

Comment: You are welcome! Now i just use hunchentoot-cgi to run an old python CGI application. It works great.  Maybe i will use hunchentoot to host other web application in the future.

Comment: I accidentally got here and noticed two errors in my answers: first, you should use #:hunchentoot or "hunchentoot" as package name. second, it's \*features\*, not *features (though it was a typo).

Answer (score 3):

It is looking for a version of SSL library you don't have. An easy way to correct it (I haven't tested the proper behavior of the library itself) is symbolic linking it. Run these in your shell:

`locate libssl`

It should return something like:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/firefox-8.0/libssl3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/thunderbird-8.0/libssl3.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so.1d
```

The one you want is most certainly **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu**, or similar, depending on your platform.

Then create the symbolic link:

`ln -s libssl3.so libssl.so`

replacing libssl3.so with the version you have installed.

Comment: On my freebsd box, there is a link: /usr/lib/libssl.so@ -> libssl.so.6, but why canot CCL find /usr/lib/libssl.so ?